# How to save only specific attribute value rather than saving the whole product in Magento2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1

As you guys already know that **we used to have this below method in magento to save a specific attribute value** like this.

```
// saving product attribute
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('id here');
$product->setName('your name here');
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'name');
```

or

```
// saving customer attribute
$customer->setData($attrCode, $value)->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer, $attrCode);
```

Can anyone let me know the **alternative of the above in Magento2** .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its the same as Magento 1

```
$dataobject->setData('attribute_code', $value);
$dataobject->getResource()->saveAttribute($dataobject, 'attribute_code');
```

<strike>This will work for any entity.</strike>

As per @Raphael's [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170025/2443) It will not work for sales attributes.

Basically it calls **Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity::saveAttribute()** function.

This will accept two parameters

```
saveAttribute(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object, $attributeCode)
```

First to be `$object` is an object which needs to be updated and second parameter will be `$attributeCode` which is the code for the attribute to be updated.

Comment: It should be basically for any entity.

Comment: Yes it will work for any entity. It will basically call `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity::saveAttribute()` which will accept a dataobject and entity code.

Comment: Upvoting it but not accepting as an answer right now. I will check and update.

Comment: Please go to line 1608 in the file. (Magento 2.1.5) there is another function `public function saveAttribute(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object, $attributeCode)`

Comment: Seems magento has basically kept all important functions intact.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of product, you can use the mass action object. For example:

```
// Edit
$productIds = [123];
$attributesData = ['name' => 'new product name'];
$storeId = 0;
$productMassAction = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action');
$productMassAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributesData, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify Jaimin's answer:

> This will work for any entity.

**This is not true.** It will only work for EAV entities which extend `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity`

If you're dealing with a non EAV entity where the resource model extends `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb` you will have to implement the `saveAttribute` method in your resource model.

In Magento 2, they have done it for the `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute` class:

```
public function saveAttribute(AbstractModel $object, $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute instanceof AbstractAttribute) {
        $attributes = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    } elseif (is_string($attribute)) {
        $attributes = [$attribute];
    } else {
        $attributes = $attribute;
    }
    if (is_array($attributes) && !empty($attributes)) {
        $this->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
        $data = array_intersect_key($object->getData(), array_flip($attributes));
        try {
            $this->_beforeSaveAttribute($object, $attributes);
            if ($object->getId() && !empty($data)) {
                $this->getConnection()->update(
                    $object->getResource()->getMainTable(),
                    $data,
                    [$object->getResource()->getIdFieldName() . '= ?' => (int)$object->getId()]
                );
                $object->addData($data);
            }
            $this->_afterSaveAttribute($object, $attributes);
            $this->getConnection()->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->getConnection()->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a product attribute value based on product id without saving the whole product itself. This saves a lot of time, especially when you have to update a bunch of products.

```php
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action;

class SomeClass
{
    /**
     * @var Action
     */
    private Action $productAction;

    /**
     * @param Action $productAction
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action $productAction
    ) {
        $this->productAction = $productAction;
    }

    public function someFunction($product)
    {
        $productIds = [$product->getId()]; // Array with one or more product ids
        $attributeUpdates = ['attribute_code' => 'value']; // Array with one or more attribute updates
        $storeId = \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID; // Scope id

        $this->productAction->updateAttributes(
            $productIds,
            $attributeUpdates,
            $storeId
        );
    }
}
```