# Save an EAV attribute in Magento2 without touching the model, repository

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

This can be done easily in magento1 with the saveAttribute() -method of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract . For example, if you only need to save the is_active -flag for a category, you can do:

```
$data = new Varien_Object();
$data->setEntityId($categoryId);
$data->setIsActive(1);

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')
    ->getResource()
    ->saveAttribute($data, 'is_active');
```

How can i do it in magento2 without using CategoryRepositoryInterface, only update one attribute?

Comment: Magento 2 does have the same function with same feature. This will help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/169828/2443